# Reestructurar tabla de doble entrada

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

quisiera ver si se puede lograr cambiar el formato de una tabla de doble entrada a un vector para posterior análisis de correlación con otras. La tabla corresponden a precipitaciones por días y está en formato calendario como se muestra en la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que quiero obtener es una columna con la fecha en números y la otra columna la precipitación del día.

Mis conocimientos en excel, python y SQL son básicos y me está costando seguir un camino, me sería de gran ayuda aunque sea una orientación.

Gracias!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Sí, se puede. ¿Qué has intentado? :)

Comment: Puedes crearte las fechas con una serie y luego traer los datos con INDICE y COINDICIR

Answer (score 0):

Terminé haciéndolo usando solamente Índice.
Hice la serie de fechas y separé en días y mes, por lo que usando éstas como número de filas y columna me encontraba la precipitación en la matriz. Obviamente en cada año cambié la matriz y la deje fija para el mismo año.
Si ven alguna falla me gustaría que me lo digan.
Saludos!